# Event.clone and Event.toString examples?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

Can anyone provide more-or-less real-world examples of when you might want to actually use these two methods of the Event class?

AS 3 makes us override these methods in any custom class that extends Event, but I wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**toString** - I only ever use this in debugging messages, but in these cases if you don't override toString then you will not be able to return a string representation of your event.  Consider this example, where a single handler is used for catching a variety of event types:

```
function handleEvents(evt:*):void
{
    //trace the event type and all parameters including extra parameters from custom events
    trace(evt.toString()); 
}
```

**clone** - If you need to re-dispatch an event, the event class's clone method will be called.  This returns a new event object with the target reassigned to the new dispatching object.  The gotcha is that if you don't override the clone method, clone will create a new event object from the last class that defined it, not from your custom event class.  This will most likely result in a type error when you catch the re-dispatched event.

Comment: Right on. I wonder whether you could provide an example of where I might wish to re-dispatch the event (presumably from within the event handler?) If you're not stopping propagation, why would you want to re-dispatch the same event, and not generate a new one?

Comment: Events can only bubble though the display tree, so if you want an event to bubble through classes that are not on the display tree you have to fake it by having event handlers that look like this: `function eventHandler(event:Event):void { dispatchEvent(event); }`

Answer (score 2):

adding to shanethehat's `toString` explanation, if you don't override `toString` and trace the event it will always print default information of a general `Event` since it is what your custom event is subclassing.

overriding `toString` is used for debugging so it's not necessary, although it's encouraged, especially if you are distributing your API, working with other developers or simply want to write clean, consistant code.

depending on the amount of properties within your custom event, you could create a switch statement so that `toString` returns only appropriate event properties for each type.  here's an example of doing so from my [HistoryEvent](https://github.com/gmattie/ActionScript-3.0/blob/master/com/mattie/events/HistoryEvent.as) class:

```
package com.mattie.events
{
    //Imports
    import flash.events.Event;

    //Class
    public class HistoryEvent extends Event
    {
        //Constants
        public static const CHANGE:String = "change";
        public static const STATUS:String = "status";

        //Variables
        public var action:String;
        public var name:String;
        public var data:Object;
        public var undoable:Boolean;
        public var undoableName:String;
        public var redoable:Boolean;
        public var redoableName:String;
        public var index:uint;

        //Constructor
        public function HistoryEvent(type:String, action:String = null, name:String = null, data:Object = null, undoable:Boolean = false, undoableName:String = null, redoable:Boolean = false, redoableName:String = null, index:uint = 0) 
        {
            super(type);

            this.action = action;
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
            this.undoable = undoable;
            this.undoableName = undoableName;
            this.redoable = redoable;
            this.redoableName = redoableName;
            this.index = index;
        }

        //Override clone
        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new HistoryEvent(type, action, name, data, undoable, undoableName, redoable, redoableName, index);
        }

        //Override toString
        override public function toString():String
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case CHANGE:    return formatToString("HistoryEvent", "type", "action", "name", "data");
                case STATUS:    return formatToString("HistoryEvent", "type", "undoable", "undoableName", "redoable", "redoableName", "index");
                default:        return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed example too. I should post a related question because your example raises a concern I had when you create a custom event class whose various event types have different related arguments. From your ex. to post a STATUS event I'm going to have to dispatchEvent(new HistoryEvent(HistoryEvent.STATUS, null, null, null, true, 'name' etc...)). From an API perspective it's a bit of a pain to have to "skip" those first three args. Does this warrant a second event type? Then what's the point of being able to define multiple types against a single custom event class...

Answer (score -2):

I've never overriden them and I always use custom events whenever it is warranted ?

Comment: you can totally f your program if you don't override `clone` and you'll pull all of your hair out before you realize the problem if you're not familiar with why it's necessary.